# Do browsers request favicon.ico even if it is not linked in the HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

I am looking for a site for somebody, and fixing errors as I find them.

There is no Favicon.. that is ok, I can fix that.

My question is, do browsers (or certain browsers, Chrome in this case) request favicon.ico as soon as they load a site.. or maybe on check that there is no alternative icon path mentioned in the source.. irrespective of whether "favicon.ico" is actually mentioned in the page source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was the original behaviour, yes. `/favicon.ico` was an *implicitly* present file which (some) browsers would check for. Only later did that actually morph into a proper standard with `<meta>` tags, arbitrary file names and image formats other than `.ico`.

Comment: I wonder how many 404's this triggers from the world's web servers each day.. where no icon file is available

Comment: Yup, quite a lot.